# In Illustrator which setting causes View->Snap To Grid to be replaced with "Snap To Pixel"

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a document that seems to have the **Snap To Grid** option replaced with **Snap To Pixel**. I'm sure that **Snap To Pixel** can also be quite useful, but right now I want to snap to a larger grid. Does anyone know what setting I might have adjusted to change the drop down options? My first thought was the checkbox **Align New Objects to Pixel Grid** that comes up when you first create a document. However I tried creating two new documents with and without. Each had the **Align To Grid** option. I've also tried toggling: **Align to Pixel Grid** in the transform panel.

I've attached images below to illustrate the option which has been replaced:

[image: Snap To Pixel]
[image: Snap To Grid]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pixel Preview** is selected in your top image - thus.... snap to pixels.

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I'm not sure why they remove the option to snap to the grid in pixel preview mode, but at least I know how to get it back now.

Comment: It's because when pixel preview is active the "grid" becomes the pixel grid. The actual Grid is generally based upon measurements and since a pixel technically has no size, there's theoretically no correlation between the Grid and pixels.

Comment: That does make some sense, but it's not inconceivable that you could want to see the pixel output while snapping to a larger grid.